# how do I post data to my nextjs api endpoint

Tags: reactjs, api, next.js, stripe-payments

I am making a test e-commerce sight to learn nextjs. I am trying to implement the checkout through stripe and I have it working if all of the information is static. when I make any of the information set to a variable it stops working and tells me that I am not passing any values into my variables. to test this I am making all of my data that needs to be passed, static data except for one which is when I get the error that I am not passing in information properly

obviously I am not sending the data to the api correctly. I think that my code looks just like the guides and docs so I am stuck. any help would be greatly appreciated.
here is the error message that I get:

"Missing required param: line_items[0][price_data][product_data][name]."

even if I change the state variable 'title' to a single value instead of an array, and in the updateState function settitle("title") I still get the same error

here is the front end code where I try to send the data to the api endpoint:

basket is an array of objects containing all of the products that the user has chosen.

```
  const [id, setId] = useState([]);
  const [price, setprice] = useState([]);
  const [description, setdescription] = useState([]);
  const [title, settitle] = useState([]);

  const updateState = () => {
    basket.forEach(element => {
          setId([...id, element.id]);
    setdescription([...description, element.description]);
    setprice([...price, element.price]);
    settitle([...title, basket.title]);
    });

    console.log(id);
    console.log(description);
    console.log(price);
    console.log(title);
  }

  //send data to the api

    const postData = async () => {  
      const response = await fetch("/api/checkout_sessions", {
        method: "POST",
        body: JSON.stringify(
          id,
          price,
          description,
          title,
        ),
      });
      return response.json();
      
    };
return (
             <form  action="/api/checkout_sessions" method="POST">
                                <button 
                                    type="submit"
                                    role="link"
                                    className="button"
                                    onClick={() => {
                                      updateState;
                                      postData;
                                    }}
                                  >
                                  proceed to checkout
                                </button>
                    </form>
)}
```

here is the api code where I try to get that data and use it which is not working how I expect:

```
const stripe = require('stripe')(process.env.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY);

export default async function handler(req, res) {


// var priceVariable ='price_1MB8P4FqoomU2P4qrVmtxCvp';
  
  
  if (req.method === 'POST') {
    const items = req.body.id
    const amount = req.body.price
    const description = req.body.description
    const title = req.body.title 
    try {
      // Create Checkout Sessions from body params.
      const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
        // shipping_options: ["shr_1MBn0HFqoomU2P4qZk4vqOQ3"],
        shipping_address_collection: {
          allowed_countries: ["US", "CA", "GB"],
        },
       line_items:[{
          price_data: { 
            unit_amount: 1000,
            currency: 'usd',
            product_data: {  
              name: title,
              description: "description",
            },
          },
          quantity: 1,
       }],
        mode: 'payment',
        success_url: `${req.headers.origin}/?success=true`,
        cancel_url: `${req.headers.origin}/?canceled=true`,
      });
      res.redirect(303, session.url);
    } catch (err) {
      res.status(err.statusCode || 500).json(err.message);
    }
  } else {
    res.setHeader('Allow', 'POST');
    res.status(405).end('Method Not Allowed');
  }
}
```

you can see in the line_items that everything is static except for the one variable that I am testing.

Answer (score 1):

JSON.stringify expects an object (https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_stringify.asp)

```
const postData = async () => {  
      const response = await fetch("/api/checkout_sessions", {
        method: "POST",
        body: JSON.stringify({
          id,
          price,
          description,
          title,
        }),
      });
      return response.json();
      
    };
```

And on the api side you may have to parse the body before accessing any properties like so

```
const body = JSON.parse(req.body)
const title = body.title
```

(https://www.w3schools.com/Js/js_json_parse.asp)

Answer (score 1):

It's unclear if the array/string mismatch is due to your testing changes, but you'll need to ensure a single string is supplied for `name`.

Your actual issue is likely here:

```
onClick={() => {
  updateState;
  postData;
}}
```

I'm surprised this is invoking the functions without `()`, but even if it were your `postData()` would start before the react state change happened.
I suspect if you initialized `title` with a value your endpoint would receive that.

const [title, setTitle] = useState("some default title");

You'll need to review how your application is tracking state here, and perhaps calculate that `title` and pass it through to the request alongside updating the state.

Comment: Unfortunately fixing those mistakes didn't change it. could you speak a little more on what you meant by "You'll need to review how your application is tracking state here"

Comment: so I put a console log in to the api and it sends the data but for some reason it doesn't let me access it.

Comment: Can you elaborate? You mean the `body` has the expected payload in the outgoing request, but you server endpoint doesn't see that?

Comment: [{"id":3,"title":"Mens Cotton Jacket","price":55.99,"description":"great outerwear jackets for Spring/Autumn/Winter, suitable for many occasions, such as working, hiking, camping, mountain/rock climbing, cycling, traveling or other outdoors. Good gift choice for you or your family member. A warm hearted love to Father, husband or son in this thanksgiving or Christmas Day.","category":"men's clothing","image":"https://fakestoreapi.com/img/71li-ujtlUL._AC_UX679_.jpg"}]

Comment: this is what I am getting but now when I use the .map function I get the error that .map if not a function. this feels like the data is being parsed as an object but I am not sure how to get it back into an array. I asked another question about this because it felt different enough to warrant another ask

Comment: ill update the question to have the current code so you can see what I have been working on

Comment: I don't see any use of `.map` in the code in the question now. Where are you hitting that?